# No PK or FK when exporting SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

We have a Production and a Staging database hosted on Microsoft Azure. We're using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 19 to do the migrating.

Here goes the steps

```
Right click the database -> Tasks -> Export Data...
```

We select `SQL Server Native Client 11.0` as the Data Source.

For authentication we select "Use SQL Server authentication" and type in our user name and password.

In "Database", we select our Production database

After clicking Next, we'll now select our destination. For Destination we use "SQL Server Native Client 11.0" and the same setup as above, but just with our Staging database as destination.

Now it's time to "Specify Table Copy or Query" and here we select "Copy data from one or more tables or views".

We now mark all the tables and select `Edit Mappings...`, where we enable `Enable identity insert`.

If we then press Next and start the migration, everything seems to be completed without any errors or warnings.

**BUT** - For some reason all our PK and FK relations are not exported into our Staging database.

We have tried to look up a single table, just to see the SQL query which are generated and it looks like the image attached.

Can anyone tell us, what we're doing wrong. We have no idea, why the PK and FK's aren't migrated. Stored procedures and everything are working as expected.

[image]

Comment: *"Export Data..."* *not* export definition. FKs and PKs aren't data. If you want to definition of the table use the Script As or Generate Scripts functionality of SSMS.

Comment: It make sense, thanks @Larnu. But is it right, that I'll need to export the data from the tables after then? I just generated a Script and all PK and FK keys are OK, but the tables are empty.

Comment: Data and definitions are 2 separate things; if you need both you need to export both.

Comment: As @Larnu said, we need to export Data and definitions. After we export Data to the destination db. We need to export PK,FK definitions script and rebuild on the target table.

Comment: Hi @Grumme If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried exporting a bacpac? That does both (but it's not suitable for large data volumes i.e. > 50Gb or so)

Answer (score 0):

There are **two ways** to export the PK and FK.

1. Using SSMS to generate the sql script. We just need to select the tables. It will generate a script.sql in your local PC.

[image]

2 We can query System tables and views to splicing FK and PK's SQL statement.

Comment: There's may more than two ways